# Вывод на экран графика функции

Tags: графика

Подскажите алгоритм вывода на экран графика произвольной математической функции БЕЗ использования  встроенной функции рисования отрезков. Т.е. вывод каждой точки - попиксельно. Есть ли в этом случае альтернатива алгоритму Брезенхема?

Comment: Можно написать соединение точек линией и вручную, но вы при этом как раз и закодируете половину алгоритма Брезенхема.

Answer (score 1):

Попиксельно высчитываем коэффициенты масштаба: ширину длину графика / ширину окна в пикселах; разницу между максимальным и минимальным значением функции в заданном диаппазоне.
Потом в цикле на каждое значение пиксела по X находим координату Y, ставим точку.

Comment: В этом случае на графике будут разрывы, нужна СПЛОШНАЯ линия

Comment: Тогда проводить линию от предыдущей точки до текущей. Она будет шириной в 1-2 пиксела.

Comment: Такой вариант: пусть по x сместились на 1 пиксель, а по y сместились вверх на n пикселей. Тогда на старой координате x рисуем вверх floor(n/2) пикселей, смещаемся вправо, рисуем вверх еще ceil(n/2) пикселей. Аналогично, если по y сместились вниз. (floor - округление к меньшему, ceil - к большему).